# How to incorporate a variable in code as a string (in the context of a for-loop)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Is there a way to express the code below with a for loop?

```
def get_data(self):
    global num_of_labels
    num_of_labels = num_of_labels + 1
    print(num_of_labels)
    if num_of_labels == 1:
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id1.text = user_input
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
    if num_of_labels == 2:
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id2.text = user_input
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
    if num_of_labels == 3:
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id3.text = user_input
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
```

I'm thinking something like this (I know the syntax is wrong here):

```
    for i in range(3)
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id+str(i).text = user_input
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
```

Where `label_id1`, `label_id2` and `label_id3` correspond to label id's in a kivy file. My problem is that I cannot express `label_id+str(i)` with proper syntax.

Here's my full code:

Python file:

```
# Variables
global num_of_labels
num_of_labels = 0; # Counter for the number of task labels

global elapsed_time
elapsed_time = 0;

global starting_time
starting_time = 0;

class TodoLayout(MDScreen, MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class CatLayout(Screen):

    # Clock

    your_time = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.padding = 10
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_time, 0.1)

    def set_time(self, dt):
        self.your_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")

    def countdown(self):
        pass


    number = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, 1)
        self.increment_time(0)

    def increment_time(self, interval):
            self.number += .1

    def start(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1)

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BullyCat(MDApp, App):

    def get_data(self):
        global num_of_labels
        num_of_labels = num_of_labels + 1
        print(num_of_labels)
        if num_of_labels == 1:
            user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id1.text = user_input
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
        if num_of_labels == 2:
            user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id2.text = user_input
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
        if num_of_labels == 3:
            user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.label_id3.text = user_input
            self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("kivyfile.kv")

    def user_input(self):
        global user_input

    def add_todo(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.get_screen('main').todo_scroll.add_widget(TodoLayout())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    BullyCat().run()
```

Kivy file:

```
WindowManager:
    TodoLayout:
    CatLayout:

<TodoLayout>:
    name: "to_do_view"
    id: to_do_view

    MDScreen:
        id: main
        name: 'main'
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0, .1
        MDLabel:
            text: "MyTasks"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .95}
            font_size: "35sp"
#           id: date
 #           text: ""
  #          pos_hint: {"center_x": .885, "center_y": .89}
   #         font_size: "18sp"

#        MDIconButton:
#            icon: "plus"
#            pos_hint: {"center_x": .92, "center_y": .925}
#            user_font_size: "30sp"
#            md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
#            theme_text_color: "Custom"
#            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
#            on_release: app.add_todo()

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "cat"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .075, "center_y": .925}
            user_font_size: "30sp"
            md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "cat_view"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        MDTextField:
            id: data
            hint_text: "Write a task"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            size_hint: 0.5, None
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: 'add'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                app.get_data()
                #app.add_todo()
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint_x: .8
            size_hint_y: .7

            MDFloatLayout:
                cols: 1
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id1
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 1'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .95}
                    size_hint_x: .5
                    size_hint_y: .15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id2
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 2'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .85}
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: 0.15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id3
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 3'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .75}
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: 0.15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id4
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 4'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .65}
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: 0.15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id5
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 5'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .55}
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: 0.15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDTextField:
                    id: label_id6
                    text: ''
                    hint_text: 'Task 6'
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .44, "center_y": .45}
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    size_hint_y: 0.15
                    font_size: 18
                    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 0
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .95}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .85}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .75}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .65}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .55}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1
                MDCheckbox:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .45}
                    size_hint_y: 0.1
                    size_hint_x: 0.1







<CatLayout>:
    name: 'cat_view'
    MDScreen:
        id: second
        name: 'second'
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 0, 1, 0, .1

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "pencil"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .075, "center_y": .925}
                user_font_size: "30sp"
                md_bg_color: 30/255, 1, 30/255, 0.8
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "to_do_view"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Time limit (min)"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
                size_hint: 0.5, None
            MDRectangleFlatButton: # Button to start timer
                id: start
                text: 'start'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .2}
                on_press: root.start()
            MDRectangleFlatButton: # Button to stop timer
                text: 'stop'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
                on_press:
                    root.stop()

            MDRectangleFlatButton: # Button to reset timer
                text: 'reset'
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .7, "center_y": .2}
                on_press: root.number = 0
            MDLabel:
                text: root.your_time
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .96, "center_y": .95}
                font_size: 15
            Image:
                source: 'cat.png'
                size_hint_x: 0.3
                size_hint_y: 0.3
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            MDLabel:
                text: str(round(root.number))
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .96, "center_y": .8}
                font_size: 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy allows to use `.ids["name"]` instead of `.ids.name`

And this allows to use string formatting

```
.ids[f"label_id{i}"].text

.ids["label_id{}".format(i)].text

.ids["label_id%s" % i].text
```

---

**EDIT:**

In doc [Accessing Widgets defined inside Kv lang in your Python code](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code) you can see example code with comment `"alternative syntax"`

```
self.ids.hulk.text = "hulk: puny god!"
self.ids["loki"].text = "loki: >_<!!!"  # alternative syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) for this:

```
    for i in range(3)
        user_input = (self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text)
        ids = self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids
        getattr(ids, f"label_id{i}").text = user_input
        self.root.get_screen("to_do_view").ids.data.text = ''
```